# Excel Match Indexing Formula for single column

Tags: excel, indexing, matching

So I'm attempting to create a column(s) that provides the year and volcano number if, in a given year, one of the event types match the eruption indicators. However, the formula I've used does not provide the values of B3 that they should. I've tried to use individual 'Match' formulas, If-Then formulas, and had no success.

[image: Formula being used]

Comment: "is not working" is not a very precise diagnosis of the problem. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58846263/edit) to expand on it?

Comment: you need to at least demonstrate the expected results and if possible let people know what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use IF:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C3,J:J,0)),B3 & A3,"")
```